# Schengen main destination

Tags: schengen, france, germany

From what I understand the main destination of a Schengen visa is the country that you will spend the most period of the trip in. I've my Schengen issued from Germany - multiple entries - and I already spent three days there. If I used it to spend three days in France would that violate the definition of the main destination or not?

Comment: Don't have any references on hand but I remember that if you're spending the same number of days in every country, apply to the country you're first arriving to, in this case Germany

Answer (score 4):

This rule is used to determine which consulate/member state should examine a visa application. It's not directly relevant if you already have a visa. Not going to your main destination at all could create problems because it might suggest you lied to get a visa but there is no explicit requirement to stay longer in the country that issued the visa.

Additionally, multiple-entry visas work somewhat differently (they are *supposed* to be used for other trips than the one you described on the application). In principle, you should get one if you have reasons to visit a country repeatedly but it's not required to go to that specific country on any given trip. Because of this, changing your plans and staying a bit longer in France is even less of a concern in your case.