# Schengen visa for non-british spouse of a british citizen

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a British national and my husband and I have recently moved to Guernsey for work. He was granted a 2.5 year spousal visa.
He also had a Schengen visa in the last 5 years.

How can we go about applying for a 3 year multi-access Schengen visa so that we may travel to European countries?

Comment: Was his spouse visa issued by the Baliwick? Or did you move after receiving the visa?

Comment: We moved after receiving the Visa - on the Visa itself it says UK entry clearance?

Comment: @GayotFow is that significant, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

> How can we go about applying for a 3 year multi-access Schengen visa so that we may travel to European countries?

Apply at the appropriate consulate.  There's no way to guarantee that they'll grant you a three-year multiple-entry visa, but your visa application will be free of charge thanks to the freedom of movement directive ([2004/38/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616)), and the decision is supposed to be made on the basis of an "expedited procedure."  So if they don't grant a multiple-entry visa, you will only have to endure minimal additional hassle.

The appropriate consulate is the one for your "main destination."  For more information, see [Schengen main destination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/59524/19400).

Comment: Thanks - would you recommend going directly to the consulate as opposed to getting a third party like TLS involved?

Comment: @Marielle I would recommend whatever seems most convenient.  For a normal visa application (not under the directive), there's not normally a choice.  In your case, however, the consulate should take the application directly.  If they resist, though, I suppose I wouldn't fight it too much.

Comment: Problem is we are situated in Guernsey and the consulate here have said they cannot help us and we must go to London - which is a pain

Comment: @Marielle If the consulate won't help, I can't help you make them.  Did you make it clear that you are British and that he will be applying under 2004/38/EC?  You can also try entering without a visa -- getting one at the border -- by traveling directly to France.  There have been a couple of questions on this site where people have reported success with this tactic.  I don't know anything about direct travel between Guernsey and France, though; the ferry company might not let your husband board without a visa.